# Convert straight line of text to curved line of text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path

In Adobe illustrator CS6, I have a lot of text. Lots of the text is the names of rivers. The text is in a straight line. Is there a way that I can change this line of text so that it curves or follows a wavy line? Or do I need to retype it using a different method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Type on a path, Envelope distort, there are a few ways. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Scott said, there are a few ways of doing it.

A simple way is to use the pen tool and draw the line in the way you want it. Then use the text tool and hover over the line you just made and the icon will change. If you click the line, you can then type and it will follow the curve.

[image: Use the pen tool to the curve]

[image: Text on the line]